# How to load an image into an imageView that is not in the active layout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I am Making an Background app and want to load the images when the first page is running but i need to load the image into ImageView in another activity which is not active(Maybe it is not possible i don't know). This maybe seem a silly question to some of u but tried to solve it for like 2 days and I cant figure it out. So i thought i should ask here.  I also Tried to find the answer on the internet but i couldn't find the answer on the internet. If this not possible then please send suggestions if you have any about what should i do. Thanks For Reading And Thinking about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you right, but it looks like you simply need to pass `image uri` by `Intent` or other way, get it inside `onResume()` and then just display it. I don't see any point in loading image into `ImageView` which **isn't visible** on the screen.

Of course if you need to load image from background thread into `ImageView` which is **visible** you can use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // here you load image
    }
});
```

Comment: can you tell me whats the best way to learn android studio is?

Comment: You need to code. Use online courses and write your own code and you're going to get better. For now I suggest `Kotlin`. It is more modern than Java and you'll find a job easier as an Android developer.

Comment: Well thanks and I am just 16 so I don't think about getting a job right now I like to do app development for fun and I use this exact methord to learn app development

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that, you are trying load image into inactive imageview to achieve faster loading of image. You can use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) to cache image before loading it, so when you need the image you'll have it on cache.

Singleton picasso instance

```java
Picasso picasso =  new Picasso.Builder(context).memoryCache(new LruCache(context)).build();
```

preload the image

```java
 picasso.load("https://image..").fetch();
```

load the image into imageview

```java
ImageView target = findViewById(..);
picasso.load("https://image..").into(target);
```

Comment: i haven't used Picasso so will the same thing work for loading a tempfile? And also it is showing cannot resolve the method with(java.context.Context)